# SQL database locking difference between SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, locking, biztalk

I am re-writing an old stored procedure which is called by BizTalk. Now this has the potential to have 50-60 messages pushed through at once. 
I occasionally have an issue with database locking when they are all trying to update at once. 
I can only make changes in SQL (not BizTalk) and I am trying to find the best way to run my SP. 
With this in mind what i have done is to make the majority of the statement to determine if an UPDATE is needed by using a SELECT statement.

What my question is - What is the difference regarding locking between an UPDATE statement and a SELECT with a NOLOCK against it?

I hope this makes sense - Thank you.

Comment: Comment to note that BizTalk as the client is irrelevant to the proper implementation of the Stored Procedure.  If the SQL App is designed to not allow concurrent updates, BizTalk can accommodate this.

Comment: Do the message arrive in a batch?  Have you considered not de-batching them in BizTalk and using a MERGE in the stored procedure to process them as a batch there?

Answer (score 3):

You use `nolock` when you want to read uncommitted data and want to avoid taking any `shared lock` on the data so that other transactions can take `exclusive` lock for updating/deleting.

You should not use `nolock` with `update` statement, it is really a bad idea, MS says that `nolock` are ignored for the target of `update/insert` statement.

> Support for use of the READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints in the FROM
>   clause that apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement
>   will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these
>   hints in this context in new development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use them.
>   [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Regarding your locking problem during multiple updates happening at the same time. This normally happens when you read data with the intention to update it later by just putting a shared lock, the following UPDATE statement can’t acquire the necessary Update Locks, because they are already blocked by the Shared Locks acquired in the different session causing the deadlock.

To resolve this you can select the records using `UPDLOCK` like following

```
DECLARE @IdToUpdate INT
SELECT @IdToUpdate =ID FROM [Your_Table] WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE A=B

UPDATE [Your_Table]
SET X=Y
WHERE ID=@IdToUpdate
```

This will take the necessary Update lock on the record in advance and will stop other sessions to acquire any lock (shared/exclusive) on the record and will prevent from any deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you - Just giving this option a go now.

Comment: Indeed i will :) - however i am still getting suspended messages which in turn will eventually turn into database locking. I will try and amended my question with a redacted version of my SP.

Answer (score 1):

**NOLOCK**: Specifies that dirty reads are allowed. No shared locks are issued to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not block the current transaction from reading the locked data. NOLOCK is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED.

Thus, while using NOLOCK you get all rows back but there are chances to read Uncommitted (Dirty) data. And while using READPAST you get only Committed Data so there are chances you won’t get those records that are currently being processed and not committed.

For your better understanding please go through below link.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/ 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4468/compare-sql-server-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints/
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19112.understanding-nolock-query-hint.aspx

Comment: Awesome - Thank you for that. Going to give those links a read.

Comment: I suggest you use READPAST instead of NOLOCK.

Comment: Note that the `NOLOCK` or `READ_UNCOMMITTED` can also result in missed or duplicated rows, not just uncommitted data.